# Ha fallado al carga del script

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo problemas cargando scripts en mi web, toto corre perfecto desde live server pero al hacerlo directamente des de el navegador me da falla de carga de script, el codigo lo tengo en un archivo aparte y es el siguiente:

```
const carrusel = document.querySelector(".slider-slides");

let maxScrollLeft = carrusel.scrollWidth - carrusel.clientWidth;

let intervalo = null;

let step = 1;
const start = () => {
  intervalo = setInterval(function () {
    carrusel.scrollLeft = carrusel.scrollLeft + step;
    if (carrusel.scrollLeft === maxScrollLeft) {
      step = step * -1;
    } else if (carrusel.scrollLeft === 0) {
      step = step * -1;
    }
  }, 10);
};

const stop = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalo);
};

carrusel.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  stop();
});

carrusel.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  start();
});

start();
```

Comment: No olvides mostrar cómo estás llamando al script desde el html.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Buen dia. Gracias por responde. Me da el siguiente mensaje:  Ha fallado la carga del <script> con origen "file:///js/slider.js".

Comment: Listo, solucionado, era un error en la llamada al script desde html. Gracias